# Why was Lagertha made mother of Bjorn?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, vikings

According to historical story/myth, [Tale of Ragnar's sons (Old Norse: Ragnarssona þáttr)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tale_of_Ragnar%27s_Sons), Bjorn's mother was Aslaug. Yet in the 2013 show **Vikings**, Bjorn's mother was Lagertha. Why was this change made? Have the directors or writers explained the difference?

Comment: Related to http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17892/is-bjorn-not-ragnars-son but I am asking about out-of-universe reasonings for the change in Mother, not the in-universe father.

Comment: I'd agree with Pelicer's answer in the sense that it makes for better storytelling. Similar reasons for making Rollo Ragnar's brother in the show even though they were not related in reality. Makes for some good tv :)

Answer (score 2):

Altought they didn't give any reasons why this change was made, there's the Lagertha reason. They needed a strong female character. This is one of VIkings's many caracteristic. You're a Viking; you're strong; you fight.

It was more of a need for a character that the watchers would love and get attached to than anything to do with the tale of Ragnar's sons.